# Is it okay to hide some Schema.org content?

Tags: seo, schema.org, hidden-text

On our site, we are using [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness).

We are using 20 properties from the list but we only want to display (have visible), as content, 3 of those properties. The remaining 17 properties should render on the page but we do not want them to be visible.

We would be using CSS `display:none` for these properties.

Is there any issue doing it this way? If yes, what is the solution?

Comment: If you're using json-ld schema then you don't need to use display:none property. It's by default not visible in layout.

Comment: What is the point in having schema for things that you don't show to users?

Comment: Schema does not, has not and will never improve SEO directly.

Answer (score 3):

According to Google's recommendations **[Structured Data General Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#technical-guidelines)**:

> Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will show up in search results: ....***The content referred to by the structured data is hidden from the user.***

Accordingly, your website may have a high risk of getting a penalty from Google. Do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

> The remaining 17 properties should render on the page but we do not want them to be visible.  We would use css "display:none" for these properties. Is there any issue doing it this way? If yes, what is the solution?

The solution is to **NOT HIDE CONTENT** that's meant to be visible. That means don't write text and apply a "display:none" css property to it. You should read google's webmaster quality guidelines.